# Left Ctrl is using Windows modifier all the time

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703, windows-key, modifier-keys

Windows key isn't pressed but every key I press with left ctrl acts as if I was pressing the windows key as well.

E.g. if I press left ctrl + C, it does ctrl + win + c (the colour filters toggle), so I can't copy and paste.

Not sure what I did to enable this or whether it's a problem with the keyboard itself. I was just typed and it suddenly started happening so I could've pressed a combination that enabled it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a keyboard tester
like this
http://www.keyboardtester.com/

See if when you press the left control if it thinks your windows key is been pressed aswell

if this is the case you may need to clean out your keyboard

Comment: You could try reinstalling your keyboard drivers in device manager